# Removing /url?q= from a link using python

Tags: python, list, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Ok first off im relatively new to python so this program I wrote might not be the most efficient, but I've ran into a problem. My program is supposed to fetch news about corona and print the titles along with the links to the newssite. I've managed to get it to print the titles and the links however the output on the links always contains `/url?q=` before the `https://`

This is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

#Fetching the site
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=corona+nyheter&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJ5eut64ztAhUliIsKHVyJDwIQ_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1920&bih=1127')
src = r.content

#Letting soup do its thing
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
data_text = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd'})
data_link = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'kCrYT'})

#Printing the titles of the news
for i in range(0, len(data_text)):
    print(str(i) + '.'+ data_text[i].text)

#Looking for links inside of the div with the class 'kCrYT'
links = []
for i in range(0, len(data_link)):
    for link in data_link[i].find_all('a'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))

#Printing each link
for i in range(0, len(links), 2):
    print(links[i])
    print('')

#print(data_link[0])
#print(dir(data_link[0]))
```

The titles work fine the problem is the output of the links which is i.e:

```
/url?q=https://www.svt.se/nyheter/utrikes/200-anstallda-smittade-med-corona-pa-minkfarmar-i-danmark&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjzgJeEgo3tAhXT7HMBHf9BAYsQxfQBMAF6BAgHEAE&usg=AOvVaw1bQmvySzBxBofyWJgMx6L_
```

But I can't figure out how to remove the `/url?q=` part of the link.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: try `.lstrip("/url?q=")`

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do this; if it's guaranteed that the same 7 characters will appear at the beginning of **every single string** you'll process, the simplest would just be to apply a substring operation:

```
link = "/url?q=https://www.svt.se/nyheter/utrikes/200-anstallda-smittade-med-corona-pa-minkfarmar-i-danmark&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjzgJeEgo3tAhXT7HMBHf9BAYsQxfQBMAF6BAgHEAE&usg=AOvVaw1bQmvySzBxBofyWJgMx6L_"
clean_link = link[7:]
print(clean_link) # https://www.svt.se/nyheter/utrikes/200-anstallda-smittade-med-corona-pa-minkfarmar-i-danmark&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjzgJeEgo3tAhXT7HMBHf9BAYsQxfQBMAF6BAgHEAE&usg=AOvVaw1bQmvySzBxBofyWJgMx6L_
```

<sup>[Repl.it](https://repl.it/@esqew/MobileShadowySphere#main.py)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can `split()` the link on `/url?q=`, and print the second index:

```
# Printing each link
for i in range(0, len(links), 2):
    print(links[i].split("/url?q=")[1])
    print('')
```

Output:

```
https://www.svt.se/nyheter/inrikes/ingen-storre-skillnad-i-skydd-mot-corona-med-munskydd-visar-dansk-studie&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjdremFhI3tAhXVPXAKHVA5DCgQxfQBMAB6BAgFEAE&usg=AOvVaw0YLZPy1QJqH0p8cmdj7Icv

https://www.svt.se/nyheter/utrikes/200-anstallda-smittade-med-corona-pa-minkfarmar-i-danmark&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjdremFhI3tAhXVPXAKHVA5DCgQxfQBMAF6BAgIEAE&usg=AOvVaw1s9zLwWfl6Yi5-t0stOmoC

https://www.svt.se/nyheter/snabbkollen/skolor-corona-stangs-ater-i-new-york&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjdremFhI3tAhXVPXAKHVA5DCgQxfQBMAJ6BAgJEAE&usg=AOvVaw0jeJ0xPGp2kcNwuLKLpRRc

https://www.svt.se/datajournalistik/corona-de-senaste-tio-veckorna/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjdremFhI3tAhXVPXAKHVA5DCgQxfQBMAN6BAgHEAE&usg=AOvVaw2_Ey5bEltmctv9NvmGymrt

https://www.svt.se/nyheter/lokalt/varmland/kor-pa-lantbruksgymnasium-smittade-av-corona&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjdremFhI3tAhXVPXAKHVA5DCgQxfQBMAR6BAgEEAE&usg=AOvVaw08P70_kTjfh_QxtxaGNTT7

https://www.svt.se/nyheter/utrikes/vaccin-mot-coronavirus-uppges-ha-95-procents-effektivitet&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjdremFhI3tAhXVPXAKHVA5DCgQxfQBMAV6BAgCEAE&usg=AOvVaw0I9PE9T-lVfPJpPTkJnO3B

https://www.svt.se/sport/artikel/alpina-landslagets-damchef-har-testats-positivt-for-corona&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjdremFhI3tAhXVPXAKHVA5DCgQxfQBMAZ6BAgAEAE&usg=AOvVaw0WojYKAkW7sikZxeZzR4m5

https://www.svt.se/nyheter/lokalt/jonkoping/sa-drabbas-utsatta-manniskor-under-pandemin&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjdremFhI3tAhXVPXAKHVA5DCgQ0Y8FMAd6BAgGEAI&usg=AOvVaw1nCkVbnm6ROrNCv4p8mcqE

https://www.expressen.se/nyheter/myndigheterna-kallar-till-presstraff-om-coronalaget/&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjdremFhI3tAhXVPXAKHVA5DCgQ0Y8FMAh6BAgDEAI&usg=AOvVaw1W77kVTR2M_69BgNjx49ve

https://www.aftonbladet.se/nyheter/a/7K5K33/fhm-undersoker-aterinsjuknande-i-corona&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjdremFhI3tAhXVPXAKHVA5DCgQ0Y8FMAl6BAgBEAI&usg=AOvVaw1pZYw6_UhTjWy79HXPSk7v
```

Answer (score 0):

`lstrip` will remove defined characters from the beginning of the string if string starts with those characters.

So simply do `.lstrip("/url?q=")` on your string.